# To show a function is in $L^r(\mu)$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(X,\mu)$ be a finite measure space and $f:X\to [-\infty,\infty]$ be such that
$$\mu\{|f|\geq \lambda\}\leq C \frac{1}{\lambda^p}, \text{for some } 1<p<\infty.$$
for some positive constant $C$. How to show that $f\in L^r(\mu), 1\leq r<p?$

I tried to split the integration for $|f|<\lambda$ and $|f|\geq \lambda$  but I could not manage to show finite the second part of integration.

Comment: Have you tried using $\int|f|^r\,\mathrm d\mu=\int_0^\infty\mu(|f|\ge\lambda)\lambda^{r-1}\,\mathrm d\lambda$?

Comment: I am not getting how that is going to help?

Answer (score 1):

Let $1\le r<p$. I let you check that
\begin{align*}
\int|f|^r\,\mathrm d\mu&=\int_0^\infty\mu(|f|^r\ge\lambda)\,\mathrm d\lambda\\[.4em]
&\le\mu(\Omega)+\int_1^\infty\mu(|f|\ge\lambda^{\frac1r})\,\mathrm d\lambda\\[.4em]
&\le\mu(\Omega)+\int_1^\infty\frac C{\lambda^{\frac pr}}\,\mathrm d\lambda\\
&<\infty.
\end{align*}

Comment: Now I get that. Thanks.